# In App purchase Subscription

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, product

In Our application we have 1 year auto renew subscription with 1 month free trial.
One of our customer bought that product but in receipt we got after 1 month expiry ("expires_date_ms": "1492425640140", "expires_date": "2017-04-17 10:40:40 Etc/GMT",) date of original purchase date. Then after 1 month validation of this receipt failed from apple.

So my question is :

> if we buy 1 year product which has 1 month free trial then do we get 13 months expiry date or 1 month expiry date ?
>
> what will happen if customer cancel the subscription before completion of 1 month free trail ?

Here is the receipt of that customer :
`{
    "expires_date_ms": "1492425640140",
    "is_trial_period": "true",
    "product_id": "**************_1Y",
    "original_purchase_date_ms": "1489747242000",
    "purchase_date_pst": "2017-03-17 03:40:40 America/Los_Angeles",
    "original_purchase_date": "2017-03-17 10:40:42 Etc/GMT",
    "transaction_id": "440000295966588",
    "expires_date_pst": "2017-04-17 03:40:40 America/Los_Angeles",
    "original_transaction_id": "440000295966588",
    "original_purchase_date_pst": "2017-03-17 03:40:42 America/Los_Angeles",
    "purchase_date_ms": "1489747240140",
    "expires_date": "2017-04-17 10:40:40 Etc/GMT",
    "web_order_line_item_id": "440000055066736",
    "quantity": "1",
    "purchase_date": "2017-03-17 10:40:40 Etc/GMT"
}`

Answer (score 0):

1.- 1 month expiry date and when auto-renew a new expiry date.
2.- If a customer cancel the subscription before completion of free trial, the customer hasn't to pay anything but if the customer makes a new buy and the free trial has expired he doesn't get a new free trial period.